# Secure authentication with PHP and LDAP without using ldap_connect

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, openldap, php-7.4

I'm working on an authentication integration with PHP 7 to authenticate to an ActiveDirectory server, for that I use basic PHP functions like `ldap_connect`.

However, this mode doesn't seem very secure to me, as it requires that at some point I have the user's credentials in plain text to be able to use the connection.

Is there a more secure way to perform this authentication?
For example, send just one request directly to the client's server and there it makes this connection to the OpenLDAP/AD server?

Comment: Are you using LDAP in a server-to-server, where you have just a single "user" that is being authenticated, for instance doing general directory listing, or are you passing individual user credentials. If the latter, once you've authenticated, do you really need to keep the credentials around, or could you just mark the session as "authenticated"?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I store this as it's a login feature I'm working on.
So every day the user will access the my system, but for that, he must first authenticate himself to the LDAP server (customer side).

Comment: And I'm assuming you don't want the user to have to re-enter their credentials, which is why you are storing them?